# Adding a PEM certificate file to Keystore in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, windows, ssl, android-studio

I am trying to do a https post but there are issues with the certificate on the server I am trying to access.  So going by [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/6378872#6378872) I need to add the certificate to a keystore.

The article suggests that I need to run the following command:

```
export CLASSPATH=bcprov-jdk16-145.jar
CERTSTORE=res/raw/mystore.bks
if [ -a $CERTSTORE ]; then
    rm $CERTSTORE || exit 1
fi
keytool \
  -import \
  -v \
  -trustcacerts \
  -alias 0 \
  -file <(openssl x509 -in mycert.pem) \
  -keystore $CERTSTORE \
  -storetype BKS \
  -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
  -providerpath /usr/share/java/bcprov.jar \
  -storepass some-password
```

Being new to Android Studio, I have no idea where this should be run.  Can somebody please give me details instructions on how to add my certificate to a Keystore from within Android Studio?

EDIT: My platform is Windows.  These seem to be commands for Unix?  If so, how do I perform the same operations on Windows?

Comment: *"I have no idea where this should be run"* - that is part of a shell script. You should run it from a Terminal. What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows.  So in Android Studio when I open the terminal and try to run it I get: *"'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the file specified."*

Comment: It's a Unix shell script.  I added the "windows" tag to increase the chances that some knowledgeable Windows user will see it.